# Replacing a SQL index text column with numeric values would make it faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have and old and very bad database.

I have a child table with a text column for the users, all my users have numeric values, but there is an exception for the admin user, the code for the admin user is 'ADMIN'.

So I created numeric code for the ADMIN user and I will update all the records with that numeric value, but I wont change the column type to integer.

So I want to know if making this change, and having all the values of the user column with numeric value, the index for user column will be better, faster and stronger?

Comment: There wont be any Bad `database`, it is how we design and maintain it. And, why woud  u wanna give datatype `varchar` column as `int `. Lot of factors associated with query performance, have u checked any execution plans and `index plan` before making changes to the column

Comment: No. Comparing 'A' to '0' is as good as comparing '1' and '0'. As long as you don't change the data type, you gain nothing.

Comment: You better look for code using `ADMIN` constant for giving access or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing performance aside, it is always better to use the database type that matches the actual type in your model. Since the actual type of the ID is integer, changing database type to `int` would make it more natural to work with your database.

For example, ordering on ID would behave in a natural way, because it would no longer alphabetize your numbers (i.e. ordering 199 ahead of 2, because 199 comes first lexicographically). Searches using `BETWEEN` operator would produce correct results for the numbers as well.

Another important improvement is that the application relying on your database would no longer be able to insert non-numeric data into the ID column by mistake. This additional validation alone is worth making the change.

As far as the size and performance of an index goes, the size is very likely to shrink, which has a potential of improving performance by reducing the amount of reads.

Comment: at least 5 applications rely on the database, so I'm making changes for those app in the meanwhile, and then the time will say if there is no longer records with the ADMIN text user; then I think I will change the type of the column to integer.

Comment: @Artemination You could also move the data to a new table, and provide the original data through a view that casts your ints to varchars, and replaces the fixed value of Admin's ID with `'ADMIN'` for backward compatibility. Then you would slowly rework the apps one by one, and drop the view when you are done. This isn't trivial business, you would have to use an "instead of" trigger on your view, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you really want a reference table.

Integers have advantages over strings for indexes:

- They are fixed length.
- They are usually shorter (although at 32 bits each, your codes might be shorter).
- I think they are easier to gather statistics on.

The first two as optimizations for the index, but they are pretty minor, and the third might affect the optimizer.  These are the sort of thing that is helpful, but you wouldn't change your data structure for it.

These also affect joins and foreign keys.  The second is particularly important for foreign key references.  If your values are wide, you end up repeating them in multiple tables -- eating up even more space.